# How to do a recursive function for linked node list

Tags: c99

Hi I have to implement a recursive function taken in input the head of a list, sum to each node all the nodes that come after. (if the list is 1->2->3 it has to become 6->5->3) and then sum all the nodes together so for example the variable`k` become 6+5+3 so `k=14`. I'm not able to implement it, can you show me how could I do that?
thx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void somma(node_t *head, int *sum);

int recursive(node_t *head, int *sum);

int main (){

    int max, i, sum=0, sum2=0;

    node_t *head = NULL;
    head = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *temp = head;

    printf("Quanti valori vuoi inserire: \n");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for (i=0; i < max; i++){
        temp->next = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        printf("Inserisci il valore in posizione %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &temp->val);
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    somma(head, &sum);

    printf("La somma e' %d\n", sum);

    recursive(head, &sum2);

    printf("La somma calcolata rec e': %d\n", sum2);

    return 0;
}

void somma(node_t *head, int *sum){

    node_t *curr = head;
    node_t *start = head;

    while(start->next != NULL){
        while (curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
            start->val += curr->val;
        }
        start = start->next;
        curr = start; 
    }

    start = head;

    while (start->next != NULL){
        (*sum) += start->val;
        start = start->next;
    }

    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those should work.

```
int sumList(LinkedList head) {
      if (head == null) return 0;
      int sum = head.value += sumList(head.next);
      return sum;
}
```

Like most recursive algorithms, define an end condition.

Then recursive and add the cumulative value to the current value and return this sum.

Comment: Sorry, this is more Java than c, but I don't have  real keyboard here.

Comment: No it doesn't I get "warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
*sum2 += head->val + recursive(head->next, sum2);"

Comment: The algorithm works. I didn't splinters, just pseudcode. You'll have to put in your pointer notation.